# multiple esp boards connection via websocket

Tags: websocket, arduino, esp32, esp8266

I try to connect multiple esp boards via websocket.
I need one esp32 as server and another esps8266 as clients, also smartphone must connect to server for controling all boards.
[image]

I try to make 2 scripts in arduino, one is server and one is client.

**Server script**

```
// Import required libraries
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>

bool ledState1 = 0;
bool ledState2 = 0;
const int ledPin = 4;

// Create AsyncWebServer object on port 80
AsyncWebServer server(80);
AsyncWebSocket ws("/ws");

const char index_html[] PROGMEM = R"rawliteral(
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
  <title>ESP Web Server</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
  <style>
  html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    color: white;
  }
  h2{
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #143642;
  }
  .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #143642;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  .content {
    padding: 30px;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .card {
    background-color: #F8F7F9;;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px 1px rgba(140,140,140,.5);
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }
  .button {
    padding: 15px 50px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0f8b8d;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
   }
   /*.button:hover {background-color: #0f8b8d}*/
   .button:active {
     background-color: #0f8b8d;
     box-shadow: 2 2px #CDCDCD;
     transform: translateY(2px);
   }
   .butt1 {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     color:#8c8c8c;
     font-weight: bold;
   }
   .butt2 {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     color:#1c1c81;
     font-weight: bold;
   }
  </style>
<title>ESP Web Server</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" href="data:,">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topnav">
    <h1>ESP WebSocket Server</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="card">

      <h2>Send to serv board</h2>
      <p class="butt1">LED1: <span id="state1">%STATE1%</span></p>
      <p><button id="button1" class="button">Toggle</button></p>

      <h2>Send to client</h2>
      <p class="butt2">LED2: <span id="state2">%STATE2%</span></p>
      <p><button id="button2" class="button">Toggle</button></p>

    </div>
  </div>
<script>
  var gateway = `ws://${window.location.hostname}/ws`;
  var websocket;
  window.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
  function initWebSocket() {
    console.log('Trying to open a WebSocket connection...');
    websocket = new WebSocket(gateway);
    websocket.onopen    = onOpen;
    websocket.onclose   = onClose;
    websocket.onmessage = onMessage; // <-- add this line
  }
  function onOpen(event) {
    console.log('Connection opened');
  }
  function onClose(event) {
    console.log('Connection closed');
    setTimeout(initWebSocket, 2000);
  }
  function onMessage(event) {
    let state1 = "---";
    let state2 = "---";
    let rcv_str = event.data;

    if (rcv_str.includes("b1_on")){
      state1 = "ON";
    }else{
      if (rcv_str.includes("b1_off")){
        state1 = "OFF";
      }
    }
    if (rcv_str.includes("b2_on")) {
      state2 = "ON";
    } else {
      if (rcv_str.includes("b1_off")){
        state2 = "OFF";
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('state1').innerHTML = state1;
    document.getElementById('state2').innerHTML = state2;
  }
  function onLoad(event) {
    initWebSocket();
    initButton();
  }
  function initButton() {
    document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', toggle1);
    document.getElementById('button2').addEventListener('click', toggle2);
  }
  function toggle1(){
    websocket.send('toggle1');
  }
  function toggle2(){
    websocket.send('toggle2');
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
)rawliteral";


void notifyClients() {
  String response;
  
  if (ledState1 == 1) {
    response += "b1_on"; 
  } else {
    response += "b1_off"; 
  }
  response += "&";
  if (ledState2 == 1) {
    response += "b2_on"; 
  } else {
    response += "b2_off"; 
  }
  Serial.print("response to clients with:");
  Serial.println(response);
  ws.textAll(response);//response clients on websocket with some data
}

void handleWebSocketMessage(void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  AwsFrameInfo *info = (AwsFrameInfo*)arg;
  if (info->final && info->index == 0 && info->len == len && info->opcode == WS_TEXT) {
    data[len] = 0;
    Serial.print("handleWebSocketMessage:");
    Serial.print((char*)data);
    Serial.println("");
    if (strcmp((char*)data, "toggle1") == 0) {
      //react on toggle string in request
      ledState1 = !ledState1;
      Serial.println(ledState1);
      notifyClients();
    } else {
      if (strcmp((char*)data, "toggle2") == 0) {
        //send to another esp
        ledState2 = !ledState2;
        Serial.println(ledState2);
        notifyClients();
      }
    }
  }
}

void onEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, AsyncWebSocketClient *client, AwsEventType type,
             void *arg, uint8_t *data, size_t len) {
  switch (type) {
    case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DATA:
      handleWebSocketMessage(arg, data, len);//recieve some from client
      break;
    case WS_EVT_PONG:
    case WS_EVT_ERROR:
      Serial.printf("ws[%s][%u] error(%u): %s\n", server->url(), client->id(), *((uint16_t*)arg), (char*)data);
      break;
  }
}

void initWebSocket() {
  ws.onEvent(onEvent);
  server.addHandler(&ws);
}
//replace $STATE$ in html on ON or OFF
String processor(const String& var){
  Serial.print("processor start, var = ");
  Serial.print(var);
  Serial.println("");

  if(var == "STATE1"){
    if (ledState1){
      return "ON";
    } else{
      return "OFF";
    }
  }
  if(var == "STATE2"){
    if (ledState2){
      return "ON";
    } else{
      return "OFF";
    }
  }
  return String();
}

void setup(){
  // Serial port for debugging purposes
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  Serial.println("Start!");

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  
// Connect to Wi-Fi
// WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
// while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
//   delay(1000);
//   Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
// }

//---- AP ----
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
  WiFi.softAP("ETarget", "passpasspass");
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("IP addr of AP: ");
  Serial.println(myIP);

  // Print ESP Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  initWebSocket();

  // for clients
  server.on("/target", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/html", "test");
  });

  // for smartphone web page
  server.on("/control", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send_P(200, "text/html", index_html, processor);//processor() is handler for /control page change
  });


  // Start server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server begin!");
}

void loop() {
  ws.cleanupClients();
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState1);
}
```

**Client script**

```
#include <SocketIOclient.h>
#include <WebSockets.h>
#include <WebSockets4WebServer.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <WebSocketsVersion.h>

//#include <WiFi.h>
// #include <WebServer.h>
//#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

const char* ssid = "ETarget";
const char* password = "passpasspass";

const char* ADDR = "192.168.4.1";

const char* URL = "/target";

const uint16_t PORT = 80;

WebSocketsClient webSocket;

int flag = 0;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
    //recv some text
    if (type == WStype_TEXT && length > 0) {
        Serial.println((char*)payload);
        flag = 1;
    }
}

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200);

    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        Serial.print(".");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("IP addr: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    webSocket.begin(ADDR, PORT, URL);

    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);

    webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);
    Serial.println("Client start!");
}


void loop() {

    webSocket.loop();

    if (millis() % 3000 == 0) {

        if (flag == 1) {
          flag = 0;
          webSocket.sendTXT("from client");
          Serial.println("data sended");
        }
    }

    // bad situation
    if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
        setup();
    }
}
```

I succesfuly connect with smartphone to server and can control server board, but i can't connect from esp8266 client to server.

Also i try this client script

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h>
 
const char* ssid     = "ETarget";
const char* password = "passpasspass";
 
char path[] = "/target";
char host[] = "192.168.4.1";
 
WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
WiFiClient client;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  delay(4000);
 
  if (client.connect(host, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  }
 
  webSocketClient.path = path;
  webSocketClient.host = host;
  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client)) {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Handshake failed.");
  }
 
}
 
void loop() {
  String data;
 
  if (client.connected()) {
 
    webSocketClient.sendData("Info to be echoed back");
 
    webSocketClient.getData(data);
    if (data.length() > 0) {
      Serial.print("Received data: ");
      Serial.println(data);
    }
 
  } else {
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
  }
 
  delay(3000);
 
}
```

Can you give me working script for my task, or show where iam wrong?

P.S. I think esp8266(client) don't make any websocket connection with esp32(server) but i don't know why.

When i connect to 192.168.4.1/control page from phone i see "WebSocket client #1 connected from 192.168.4.3" in Serial.
When esp8266(client) trying to connect to 192.168.4.1/target page i don't get any Serial info.
When i try to open 192.168.4.1/target on my phone browser recieve "test" string but don't get websocket(coz its just text, no JS stuff).

Comment: `webSocketEvent()` return `type` which provide [rich information](https://github.com/Links2004/arduinoWebSockets/blob/master/examples/esp8266_pico/WebSocketClient/WebSocketClient.ino#L22-L58) for diagnostic.

Comment: @hcheung
i don't have any output from server esp32 when i poweron my client esp8266.

Comment: I'm referring to your WebSocket client, Did you even try or read the link? Your problem as you described is " i can't connect from esp8266 client to server." If your web socket client can't connect, how do you expecting the server show anything?